# Laravel + vite, Laravel not reading HMR files unless run build

Tags: laravel, vite

I am having issues with a fresh installation using docker + laravel + vite.

I can currently load the blade template successfully, however, when I load my file in `resources/js/app.js`, it is failing as it cannot find the file.

In my blade template, I use `@vite('resources/js/app.js')` to load this file.

If I run `npm run build` it loads the file successfully, but if I am working with them by using the HRM `npm run dev`, laravel cannot find this file.

How can I resolve this? Should I move to `mix` for this?

Answer (score 1):

Vite port was not exposed in my dockerfile. Now it works perfectly :D